# Add custom font to Word Document

Tags: xml, fonts, ms-word, ms-office, docx

I need to set up a Word Template for a multi user office with different operating systems (Mac and Windows). I have Office 2016 for Mac and it does not offer the possibility to embed fonts into the .docx / .dotx container.

Can I add somehow my custom fonts to the container manually? I have created a test file and decompressed it thus I see the actual XML files. I have looked at word/fontTable.xml but it shows only information about used fonts:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<w:fonts xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main" xmlns:w14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordml" xmlns:w15="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2012/wordml" mc:Ignorable="w14 w15">
<w:font w:name="Calibri">
    <w:panose1 w:val="020F0502020204030204"/>
    <w:charset w:val="00"/>
    <w:family w:val="auto"/>
    <w:pitch w:val="variable"/>
    <w:sig w:usb0="E00002FF" w:usb1="4000ACFF" w:usb2="00000001" w:usb3="00000000" w:csb0="0000019F" w:csb1="00000000"/>
</w:font>
<w:font w:name="DengXian">
    <w:panose1 w:val="02010600030101010101"/>
    <w:charset w:val="86"/>
    <w:family w:val="auto"/>
    <w:pitch w:val="variable"/>
    <w:sig w:usb0="A00002BF" w:usb1="38CF7CFA" w:usb2="00000016" w:usb3="00000000" w:csb0="0004000F" w:csb1="00000000"/>
</w:font>
<w:font w:name="Times New Roman">
    <w:panose1 w:val="02020603050405020304"/>
    <w:charset w:val="00"/>
    <w:family w:val="auto"/>
    <w:pitch w:val="variable"/>
    <w:sig w:usb0="E0002AEF" w:usb1="C0007841" w:usb2="00000009" w:usb3="00000000" w:csb0="000001FF" w:csb1="00000000"/>
</w:font>
<w:font w:name="Arial">
    <w:panose1 w:val="020B0604020202020204"/>
    <w:charset w:val="00"/>
    <w:family w:val="auto"/>
    <w:pitch w:val="variable"/>
    <w:sig w:usb0="E0002AFF" w:usb1="C0007843" w:usb2="00000009" w:usb3="00000000" w:csb0="000001FF" w:csb1="00000000"/>
</w:font>
<w:font w:name="DengXian Light">
    <w:panose1 w:val="02010600030101010101"/>
    <w:charset w:val="86"/>
    <w:family w:val="auto"/>
    <w:pitch w:val="variable"/>
    <w:sig w:usb0="A00002BF" w:usb1="38CF7CFA" w:usb2="00000016" w:usb3="00000000" w:csb0="0004000F" w:csb1="00000000"/>
</w:font>
<w:font w:name="Calibri Light">
    <w:panose1 w:val="020F0302020204030204"/>
    <w:charset w:val="00"/>
    <w:family w:val="auto"/>
    <w:pitch w:val="variable"/>
    <w:sig w:usb0="A00002EF" w:usb1="4000207B" w:usb2="00000000" w:usb3="00000000" w:csb0="0000019F" w:csb1="00000000"/>
</w:font>
</w:fonts>
```

I want to include the custom font within the container and use it, so the fonts I included in the template and independent from the machine the template is used on.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

i think you might be able to do this in the following way

1. Get the OOXML of a blank document using the fonts you need (using the range.getOoxml() functionality of the API). Manually aggregate the fonts you need beforehand.
2. Store This OOXML and insert it in the new documents as needed (using the range.insertOoxml() method)
3. After you insert the OOXML with the fonts you should be able to use it in the range.font.name = "font name"

getOOXML sample:

```js
Word.run(function (context) {
//make sure you previously add the fonts you need!
             var myOOXMLTest = context.document.body.getOoxml();
             return context.sync()
             .then(function () {
                var  returnOoxmlWithFonts = myOOXMLTest.value; // this is the OOXML you need to insert when you want to sue the fonts.

             })


         })
```

insertOOXML sample:

```js
  Word.run(function (ctx) {
          
             ctx.document.getSelection().insertOoxml(OOXML, "replace"); // use the OOXML obtained before!
             return ctx.sync();
             

         });
```